# Only show div when in the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping to fade in a div when the page has been scrolled away from the top of the page, however I want this div to be hidden again when approaching the bottom of the page.

To be specific, I want the div to be hidden when within 200px of the top or 200px of the bottom.

I have two scripts which work independently, but when both active, a conflict between the two causes the div to flash in and out of view.

How would I combine the following scripts to avoid this conflict? Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('#myDiv').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('#myDiv').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
           $('#myDiv').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('#myDiv').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it happening when the window is 400px tall? Does each one work independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how's this:

```js
$(function () {
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function () {
      var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        // only fadeIn between 200 from top and 200 from bottom
        if (scrollTop  > 200 && scrollTop <  $(document).height() - $window.height() - 200) {
            $('#myDiv').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('#myDiv').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldn7qkqv/)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! If I want it to make it do the opposite, so it fades in after 200px from the top (so the div is only visible when in the middle of the page), could I just switch the fade in and out values around?

Comment: If you wanted it opposite (fadeIn 200 from top and 200 from bottom), then yep just swap the fadeIn and fadeOut.  I have added a fiddle to the answer so you can have a play around with it

Comment: My mistake, your solution is exactly what I was after!

Comment: Done it. Thanks a lot!