# Show div when window equals div but hide when the window has passed the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a div to appear when i'm scrolling over a specific div but want to hide it when you scroll past that div.

I was able to make it so that when the window reaches the top of a div to show my button: [Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo7Ley5e/) `.`

I saw this solution for a height range but couldn't replicate it to work for this: [Only show div when in the middle of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945955/only-show-div-when-in-the-middle-of-the-page)

How do I hide the div when you scroll past the red div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check to your if statement that checks if the button is less than the top position of the div you want it disappear on.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.separator').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('#header').offset().top) {
        $('#button').show();            // Show the arrow
    } else {
        $('#button').hide();            // Hide the arrow
    }   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vo7Ley5e/2/

Comment: Worked perfectly. When I attempted to replicate I was using the same element #header for both pieces. Using .separator worked!